# Overdraw Eclipse RCP application's main shell

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I've been trying to "overdraw" my Eclipse RCP application's main window in order to display a red "recording" border when the application has it's screen recording feature enabled.

```
private boolean isActive;

private final ProgressMonitorDialog monitor;

private PaintListener paintListener;
private final int recordingFrameThickness = 5;  

public boolean toggle() {
  isActive = !isActive;

  try {
    // New state
    if (isActive) {
      monitor.run(true, false, new BackupExecutionBeginRecording(Display.getCurrent()));
      addRecordingFrame(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell());
    }
    else {
      monitor.run(true, false, new BackupExecutionAfterRecording());
      removeRecoringFrame(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell());
    }
  }
  catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    System.err.println("Couldn't start backup task. Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
  catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.err.println("Backup thread was interrupted. Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }

  return isActive;
}

private void addRecordingFrame(Shell shell) {
  paintListener = new PaintListener() {

    @Override
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
      Rectangle clientArea = shell.getClientArea();
      e.gc.setLineWidth(recordingFrameThickness);
      e.gc.setForeground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
      e.gc.drawRectangle(clientArea);
    }
  };

  shell.addPaintListener(paintListener);
}

private void removeRecoringFrame(Shell shell) {
  shell.removePaintListener(paintListener);
}
```

As you can see, the approach I followed is to wait until the applications main window is painted and add a rectangle afterwards. In theory, after every change of the window size or position, the overlayed red frame should be rendered again. But it seems that the PaintEvent is not invoked by the application's main shell.

Is there an other way to draw something onto the existing layout of the application without blocking the interaction with the controls below?

Comment: Paint listeners work on a Shell (at least on macOS). What shell are you trying to update - check which shell `Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell()` is giving you,

Comment: Hi greg! Thank you for your reply. I checked the passed shell parameter and its the same as the main application - at least if I can trust that the shell name is the same as the application's title. Plus I'm able to grab screenshots of the display using GC and receive the mouse coordinates via this specific shell.

Comment: An update on this: It seems that the shell paint is called once and not, as I assumed, on every change of the shells position or size. I'll post my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eclipse Platform does this by creating and painting on an *overlay* shell that is carefully positioned over top of the base shell.  The overlay is created with `SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.ON_TOP` and its position tracks the underlying base shell.  See the e4 [Overlay](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt/src/org/eclipse/e4/ui/workbench/addons/dndaddon/Overlay.java?h=master) for an example.

Comment: Hi Brian! Thanks for posting your answer. I couldn't get your referenced implementation to work properly with Eclipse 4.5 but making a few adjustments, I achieved a satisfying solution.

Answer (score 0):

With the solution below, I was able to draw a red border around my main shell which "follows" any repositioning and resizing activity of the shell. A big drawback remains: The red colored border seems to have an outer border (created by the region?) which overlaps the handles used to resize the shell. Due to this, resizing of the shell is only possible when the red border isn't displayed (equals the shell has no focus).

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ControlEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ControlListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ShellEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ShellListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Region;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class RecordingFrame {

    private Shell baseShell;
    private Shell overlayShell;

    private ControlListener controlListener;
    private ShellListener shellListener;
    private PaintListener paintListener;

    private Rectangle outerRect;
    private Rectangle innerRect;
    private Region region;

    private int lineWidth = 10;
    private Color color;

    public RecordingFrame(Shell baseShell) {
        this.baseShell = baseShell;

        // Set up new shell
        overlayShell = new Shell(baseShell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.ON_TOP);
        overlayShell.setVisible(true);

        // Initialize objects
        outerRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
        innerRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
        region = new Region();

        color = new Color(baseShell.getDisplay(), 255, 0, 0);

        // First drawing of frame
        redraw();

        // Configure listeners
        initListeners();

        // Add listeners to shells
        baseShell.addControlListener(controlListener);
        baseShell.addShellListener(shellListener);
        overlayShell.addPaintListener(paintListener);
    }

    public void dispose() {
      // Remove all listeners
      overlayShell.removePaintListener(paintListener);
        baseShell.removeControlListener(controlListener);
        baseShell.removeShellListener(shellListener);

        if (!overlayShell.isDisposed())
            overlayShell.dispose();
    }

    private void redraw() {

      // Get bounds of base shell
        overlayShell.setBounds(baseShell.getBounds());

        // Calculate outer rectangle
        outerRect.height = overlayShell.getBounds().height;
        outerRect.width = overlayShell.getBounds().width;
        outerRect.x = 0;
        outerRect.y = 0;

        // Calculate inner rectangle
        innerRect.height = outerRect.height - 2 * lineWidth;
        innerRect.width = outerRect.width - 2 * lineWidth;
        innerRect.x = 0 + lineWidth;
        innerRect.y = 0 + lineWidth;

        // Create a new region which is the outer shell minus the inner shell
        region = new Region();
        region.add(outerRect);
        region.subtract(innerRect);

        overlayShell.setRegion(region);
        region.dispose();

        // Draw rectangle with new GC
        GC gc = new GC(overlayShell);
        gc.setLineWidth(lineWidth);
        gc.setForeground(color);
        gc.drawRectangle(innerRect);
        gc.dispose();
    }

    private void initListeners() {
       controlListener = new ControlListener() {

          @Override
          public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
            redraw();
          }

          @Override
          public void controlMoved(ControlEvent e) {
            redraw();
          }
        };

        shellListener = new ShellListener() {

          @Override
          public void shellIconified(ShellEvent e) {
            overlayShell.setVisible(false);        
          }

          @Override
          public void shellDeiconified(ShellEvent e) {
            overlayShell.setVisible(true);                
          }

          @Override
          public void shellDeactivated(ShellEvent e) {
            overlayShell.setVisible(false);         
          }

          @Override
          public void shellClosed(ShellEvent e) {
            dispose();        
          }

          @Override
          public void shellActivated(ShellEvent e) {
            overlayShell.setVisible(true);          
          }
        };

        paintListener = new PaintListener() {

          @Override
          public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            redraw();
          }
        };
    }
}
```